# MySQL UNION 2 sets with results from 1 table

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `eurojackpot` (
`datum_trekking` date NOT NULL,
`g1` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
`g2` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
`g3` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
`g4` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
`g5` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
`b1` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
`b2` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `datum_trekking` (`datum_trekking`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I perform the query below and it gives partially the result set I am looking for.

```
(SELECT g1 AS Nummer, count(*) AS Aantal
FROM  
( 
SELECT  g1 FROM  eurojackpot
  WHERE datum_trekking >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    UNION  ALL 
SELECT  g2 FROM  eurojackpot
  WHERE datum_trekking >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    UNION  ALL 
SELECT  g3 FROM  eurojackpot
  WHERE datum_trekking >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    UNION  ALL 
SELECT  g4 FROM  eurojackpot
  WHERE datum_trekking >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    UNION  ALL 
SELECT  g5 FROM  eurojackpot
  WHERE datum_trekking >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
) y
GROUP BY  g1
ORDER BY Aantal
DESC
LIMIT 5
)
UNION
(SELECT b1 AS Bonus, count(*) AS aantal_b
FROM  
( 
SELECT  b1 FROM  eurojackpot
  WHERE datum_trekking >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    UNION  ALL 
SELECT  b2 FROM  eurojackpot
  WHERE datum_trekking >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
) z
GROUP BY  b1
ORDER BY aantal_b
DESC
LIMIT 5)
```

The above query ouputs the following set of data:

```
+-------+--------+
+Nummer + Aantal +
+-------+--------+
+ 3     + 2      +
+ 22    + 2      +
+ 25    + 2      +
+ 41    + 2      +
+ 35    + 2      +
+ 4     + 3      +
+ 2     + 2      +
+ 8     + 2      +
+ 5     + 2      +
+ 3     + 1      +
+-------+--------+
```

What I am looking for is a table with output like this:

```
+-------+--------+-------+----------+
+Nummer + Aantal + Bonus + aantal_b +
+-------+--------+-------+----------+
+ 3     + 2      + 4     + 3        +
+ 22    + 2      + 2     + 2        +
+ 25    + 2      + 8     + 2        +
+ 41    + 2      + 5     + 2        +
+ 35    + 2      + 3     + 1        +
+-------+--------+-------+----------+
```

What is query basically does is counting the occurrences of the numbers and limits it to 5 numbers with the highest occurrence. It should count the numbers for the columns g1 through g5 and b1 to b2.
Any hint and tips are much appreciated. I think I am overlooking something, but can't find the last bit to get this query to work properly

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question doesn't quite explain how the columns and rows are calculated.

Comment: 1. See normalization

Comment: @Gordon: I will update the tables in my question

Answer (score 0):

Do a `Join` instead of a `UNION`:

```
SELECT yy.Nummer, yy.Aantal, zz.Bonus, zz.aantal_b
FROM
(
SELECT 
    g1 AS Nummer, 
    count(*) AS Aantal
FROM  ( 
    SELECT  g1 FROM  eurojackpot
        WHERE datum_trekking >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g2 FROM  eurojackpot
        WHERE datum_trekking >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g3 FROM  eurojackpot
        WHERE datum_trekking >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g4 FROM  eurojackpot
        WHERE datum_trekking >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g5 FROM  eurojackpot
        WHERE datum_trekking >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
) y
GROUP BY  g1
ORDER BY Aantal
DESC
LIMIT 5
) yy
JOIN
(SELECT b1 AS Bonus, count(*) AS aantal_b
FROM  
( 
SELECT  b1 FROM  eurojackpot
  WHERE datum_trekking >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    UNION  ALL 
SELECT  b2 FROM  eurojackpot
  WHERE datum_trekking >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
) z
GROUP BY  b1
ORDER BY aantal_b
DESC
LIMIT 5) zz
ON y.g1 = z.b1
```

Comment: when I run this query I get the following error: #1054 - Unknown column 'yy.g1' in 'field list'. Any ideas?

Comment: Yepp, had a small issue with the alias names of the columns. I updated the query in my answer.

Comment: Hi @Benni, I get the following error: #1054 - Unknown column 'y.g1' in 'on clause'. When I change the values in the ON close to yy.Nummer and zz.Bonus or yy.Aantal and zz.aantal_b it returns positive results, but not the desired set. Any further ideas?